# I'm doing type conversions in C++. Came across this program and I don't understand how the constructor `rec(polar p)` is being called

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class polar
{
    float r,ang;
    public:
        polar()
        {
            r=0;
            ang=0;
        }
        polar(float m,float n)
        {
            r=m;
            ang=n;
        }
        float getr()
        {
            return r;
        }
        float getang()
        {
            return ang;
        }
        void showpolar()
        {
            cout<<r<<", "<<ang<<endl;
        }   
};                       
class rec
{
    float x,y;
    public:
        rec()
        {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }
        rec(float xc, float yc)
        {
            x=xc;
            y=yc;
        }
        void showrec()
        {
            cout<<x<<","<<y<<endl;
        }
        rec(polar p)
        {
            float rv = p.getr();
            float av = p.getang();
            x=rv*cos(av);
            y=rv*sin(av);
        }
};

int main()
{
    polar p1(2,45);
    rec r1;
    r1=p1;
    cout<<"Ploar coordinate is:";
    p1.showpolar();
    cout<<"Rectangle coordinate is:";
    r1.showrec();
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I don't understand how the rec(polar p) constructor is being called. I understand that r1=p1 is calling it but don't understand how. There isn't any operator overloading where '=' acts as a function. So, I don't actually get how the rec(polar p) constructor is being called.
I'm doing type conversions in c++, also is there a better way of doing it which makes the program clear? I feel like this is the simplest form but I still dont get whats happening.

Comment: See [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) and try `explicit rec(polar p)`. `rec::rec(polar p)` can be used by the compiler to perform implicit conversion from `polar` to `rec`.

Comment: Essentially the compiler knows how to assign a `rec` to a `rec`, and it knows how to convert a `polar` to a `rec`, so it knows how to assign a `polar` to a `rec`. `operator=` by default accepts not only `rec` but anything that can be implicitly converted to `rec`.

Comment: If you want to feel better about your confusion, Kate Gregory's presentation touches upon C++'s [*all the defaults are wrong*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYVxGyido9g).  Unfortunately, it's way too late to fix the problem, short of making a different language.  That ship has sailed.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a constructor can is considered a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

> A constructor that is not declared with the specifier explicit and which can be called with a single parameter (until C++11) is called a converting constructor.

When it comes to C++11, any constructor that is not prefixed with the keyword `explicit` is a converting constructor.

A converting constructor is called when type conversion is required. Back to your example, The `r1=p1` is impossible because `r1` and `p1` are of different types. However, the compiler notices the converting constructor `rec (polar r)` can convert a `polar` object into a `rec` object, which will make the assignment legal. So the assignment triggers the constructor `rec (polar p)` to construct a temporary `rec` object and this temporary object is assigned to `r1`.

To prevent such conversion, use [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)